# Proving that 2 numbers are different without revealing them

Tags: zero-knowledge-proofs

Imagine that Alice generates a number $a$ and Bob generates a number $b$. Is there a way that they can check that $a \not = b$ without revealing any information on $a$ and $b$ (Alice must not know $b$ and Bob must not know $a$) ?

Comment: You are having the [Socialist Millionaire Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Socialist_millionaires) with the boolean output inverted.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, this is a standard secure two computation problem. There was a classic paper discussing this from many years ago called [Comparing Information Without Leaking It](https://www.stat.berkeley.edu/users/aldous/157/Papers/fagin.pdf). There are more efficient methods today (in fact, the oblivious transfer method today is very efficient using [oblivious transfer extensions](https://eprint.iacr.org/2015/546.pdf)).